# VS 2017 Post Build Event Exit Code 3, Works in CMD

Tags: .net, visual-studio, powershell

I am trying to execute the following command:

```
"$(SolutionDir)packages\Centeva.Ct-TypeScripter.1.1.13\tools\TypeScripter.exe" .\typescripter.settings.json
```

and I get the following error:

```
The command ""C:\Users\marbl\Desktop\pulse\packages\Centeva.Ct-TypeScripter.1.1.13\tools\TypeScripter.exe" .\typescripter.settings.json" exited with code 3.
```

If I take and execute the output of the error

```
"C:\Users\marbl\Desktop\pulse\packages\Centeva.Ct-TypeScripter.1.1.13\tools\TypeScripter.exe
```

In cmd/powershell it works just fine. I have verified all files exist and are in the correct location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSVS Builder error code 3 is a "path error":

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

```
ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND
    3 (0x3)
    The system cannot find the path specified.
```

- SUGGESTION:

  Try specifying an absolute path setting for typescripter.settings.json.
- You might also try eliminating the double-quotes:

  EXAMPLE:

  `$(SolutionDir)packages\Centeva.Ct-TypeScripter.1.1.13\tools\TypeScripter.exe`

Comment: Thanks. Another piece of advice. I found out that if you look at the output window it has a better error. Thanks.